# Escape single quote in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file like the sample below:

```
27/04/22;8888888;LBB blablalbla;5 000;5 000;0;0;53707;1;WWW;
27/04/22;8888888;"LBB blablalbla;15 000;15 000;0;0;53707;1;WWW;
27/04/22;8888888;LBB blablalbla;10 000;10 000;0;0;53707;1;WWW;
```

I am not able to read it correctly with *csv* python module because on the second line there is a double quote but no end of quote.
The result is that the rest of the csv file is stored in the same dict value.

I am using *csv.DictReader* function but I do not find any option to not take this double quote into account.

Do I need to rewrite the .csv file before working with this function?

Comment: You can simply remove that double quote and then do rest your actions

Comment: how often can things like this happen? if it's only once you can manually remove it. if it happens often you can create a pre-processing function where you read the csv line by line, clean it and store it again cleaned. then run your csv.reader normally

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki as I am reading csv from another source I do not know when this exception can happen but it can happen again :) I will go for a pre-processing function thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to rewrite the .csv file before working with this function?

No, you can use [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) as follows, let `file.csv` content be

```
27/04/22;8888888;LBB blablalbla;5 000;5 000;0;0;53707;1;WWW;
27/04/22;8888888;"LBB blablalbla;15 000;15 000;0;0;53707;1;WWW;
27/04/22;8888888;LBB blablalbla;10 000;10 000;0;0;53707;1;WWW;
```

then

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"],delimiter=";",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

gives output

```
OrderedDict([('A', '27/04/22'), ('B', '8888888'), ('C', 'LBB blablalbla'), ('D', '5 000'), ('E', '5 000'), ('F', '0'), ('G', '0'), ('H', '53707'), ('I', '1'), ('J', 'WWW'), ('K', '')])
OrderedDict([('A', '27/04/22'), ('B', '8888888'), ('C', '"LBB blablalbla'), ('D', '15 000'), ('E', '15 000'), ('F', '0'), ('G', '0'), ('H', '53707'), ('I', '1'), ('J', 'WWW'), ('K', '')])
OrderedDict([('A', '27/04/22'), ('B', '8888888'), ('C', 'LBB blablalbla'), ('D', '10 000'), ('E', '10 000'), ('F', '0'), ('G', '0'), ('H', '53707'), ('I', '1'), ('J', 'WWW'), ('K', '')])
```